# How do you only show duplicate rows based on a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I am wanting to show all rows through either a query function or array formula that have a duplicate cell reference in Column B and where it shouldn't matter if Column A doesn't match.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Title 1 | URL 1 |
| Title 4 | URL 4 |
| Title 2 | URL 2 |
| Title 2 | URL 2.1 |
| Title 3 | URL 3 |
| Title 5 | URL 2 |
| Title 7 | URL 1 |

The result should be the following:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Title 1 | URL 1 |
| Title 7 | URL 1 |
| Title 2 | URL 2 |
| Title 5 | URL 2 |

How do I accomplish only showing duplicate records with a unique records in Column A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`=arrayformula(query({"Dupe",A1:B1;if(B2:B<>"",if(countif(iferror(vlookup(B2:B,{B:B,row(B:B)},2,false),""),row(B2:B))=1,,true),),A2:B},"select Col2,Col3 where Col1 = true order by Col3,Col2",1))`

[image]

Or without `query`:

`={A1:B1;sort(filter(A1:B,countif(vlookup(B1:B,{B:B,row(B:B)},2,false),row(B1:B))<>1),2,1,1,1)}`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:B, 
 COUNTIFS(B1:B, B1:B, ROW(B1:B), "<="&ROW(B1:B))>1))
```